# Splitting of String delimited by '[' and ']'

Tags: java, string, parsing, split

I have some sampel data written on a file. The data are in the following format -

```
[Peter Jackson] [UK] [United Kingdom] [London]....
```

I have to extract the information delimited by '[' and ']'. So that I found -

```
Peter Jackson  
UK  
United Kingdom  
London  
...
...
```

I am not so well known with string splitting. I only know how to split string when they are only separated by a single character (eg - string1-string2-string3-....).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use regex for this.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]");
Matcher results = p.matcher("[Peter Jackson] [UK] [United Kingdom] [London]....");

while (results.find()) {
    System.out.println(results.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
\\[(.+?)\\]
```

And the captured group will have your content.

Sorry for not adding the code. I don't know java

Comment: In Java it would be string.split(regex)

Comment: @BrianJ: No, you will have to use a matcher to find the matches.

Answer (score 2):

Is each item separated by spaces? if so, you could split by "\] \[" then replace all the left over brackets:

```
    String vals = "[Peter Jackson] [UK] [United Kingdom] [London]";
    String[] list = vals.split("\\] \\[");
    for(String str : list){
        str = str.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "");
        System.out.println(str); 
    }
```

Or if you want to avoid a loop you could use a substring to remove the beginning and ending brackets then just separate by "\\] \\[" :

```
    String vals = " [Peter Jackson] [UK] [United Kingdom] [London] ";
    vals = vals.trim(); //removes beginning whitspace
    vals = vals.substring(1,vals.length()-1); // removes beginning and ending bracket
    String[] list = vals.split("\\] \\[");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace

```
    String str = "[Peter Jackson] [UK] [United Kingdom] [London]";
    str = str.replace("[", "");
    str = str.replace("]", "");
```

And then you can try to split it.

Comment: That *removes* the (important!) separators! You cannot reliably split the remaining string anymore.

Comment: True, didn't think about that! so you have to split before you replace then

Answer (score 1):

Splitting on "] [" should sort you, as in:

```
\] \[
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/1MfEjvut35IKbBYl)

After this, just replace the '[' and the ']' and join using newline.